# How can I quickly delete ALL texts on an unrooted phone?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sms

On a rooted phone, I merely delete `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db` and then reboot.

Is there anything similarly quick that can be done on an unrooted phone?

I have a phone that has upwards of 50k texts and every app is hanging when trying to delete a single conversation.

(Android 6.0.1)

Answer (score 3):

Not near as quick, but [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) app and other SMS management apps can do this, also many SMS messenger apps can do this as well, but without root you cannot do it manually.

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to use the same method that the texting apps use, which is to say, it never does anything, even over night.

Comment: @Trel Odd... I just did a backup and tried it with about 5000 SMS messages, it took 2-3 seconds on my unrooted Moto X Pure Edition on Android 6.0 to delete all SMS and call logs. What device are you using?

Comment: Nexus 5 with 6.0.1.  You said you have 5000 messages, but that's just the problem.  I have at least ten conversations with 5000 a piece.  None of the text apps I use (stock or Chomp) support pruning.

Comment: Can you go to Settings - Apps and find Message Storage and clear cache and data?

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't need root to done this, You can simply go to Settings, Apps and find message service then click Clear cache and storage.

Comment: "find message service" ?!?!? there is not

Comment: @Zibri It may be balled Message Storage, and you need to "Show System" using the 3-dot menu in the upper right corner.

Comment: nevermind I didi it trhough adb with pm clear

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is this a useful answer to this question.

My problem was, I need to delete all the conversation from my messages app on my phone.
Since I'm a stock Android user from the past 5 years, all the messages from 5 years still exist in my new android phone (now I'm using pixe2).
Why? , because google will sync all conversations with google account.

There is no option in default messages app to delete all conversation. 
I tried to clear app data, but not worked. Because Google will sync all the conversation back again to my phone.
I tried to install other SMS apps but it not showing old conversations on my google account.

Finally, I found an app from Microsoft in the Google play store
"SMS Organizer - Clean, Reminders, Offers & Backup"

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.android.smsorganizer

It will sync conversations from google account and it has the option to delete all conversations. It worked..